# Passing 2d Array from ajax to controller ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm new in this Asp.Net MVC. How to pass 2d Array from ajax request to controller. I'm passing this array to parameter in my Controller but it gives me a null value. Here's my code:

View script

```
$("#UpdatePosition").click(function () {
var positions = [];
$('.updated').each(function () {
    positions.push([$(this).attr('data-index'), $(this).attr('data-position')]);
    $(this).removeClass('updated');
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    async: false,
    traditional: true,
    //contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateCategoryGroupPosition", "Admin")',
    data: { data: positions }, //Sample position data = [1,1], [2,2], [3,3]
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == true) {
                alert("sucess")
            }else{
                alert("failed")
            }

        }, error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
});
```

in Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateCategoryGroupPosition(string[][] data)
{
    var result = false;

    try
    {
        if (data!= null)
        {
            
            }
            result = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solve my problem. Thank you @Amit Kotha for helping me Here's the solution

In View

```
$("#UpdatePosition").click(function () {
var positions = [];
$('.updated').each(function () {
    positions.push([$(this).attr('data-index'), $(this).attr('data-position')]);
    $(this).removeClass('updated');
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    async: false,
    traditional: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateCategoryGroupPosition", "Admin")',
    data: JSON.stringify({ data: positions }),

    success: function (result) {
        if (result == true) {
            alert('success')
        }
      

    }, error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    }
 });
});
```

In Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateCategoryGroupPosition(int[][] data)
{
var result = false;

try
{
    if (data != null)
    {
        foreach (var _pos in data)
        {

            int index = _pos[0];
            int value = _pos[1];

            //update query

        }
        result = true;

    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}

return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated javascript which I just ran and it gave me correct result

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var postions = [[1, 1], [2, 2],[3,3]];
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            dataType:"JSON",
            async:false,
            traditional:true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            url: "/Home/UpdateCategoryGroupPosition",
            data: { data:postions },

            success: function (data) {
                $('#alertMessage').html(data);
            }
        });

    });
```

[image]

Comment: then I can call the position[0] and position[1] like this? because the value of position like for example position = { [1,1], [2,2], [3,3] }

Comment: Not working. It passing a null value in position on the controller :(

Comment: The Form Data is {"position":[["2","1"],["3","2"],["4","3"],["1","4"]]}: but it return null

Comment: I edited some code based on your answer but it gives me a null value :( . Thank you so much for helping me mate!

Comment: and also I commented the contentType because it gives me a server error 500